# Angular - Rendering a collection of child controls without a FormArray?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

**TL,DR;**

When a collection of child controls is not a [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray), how can it be rendered?

```
// 'foo', 'bar' and 'baz' are actually names chosen by the user.
// and are *not* known ahead-of-time.

let form = this.fb.group({
    fields: this.fb.group({
      foo: this.fb.control(''),
      bar: this.fb.control(''),
      baz: this.fb.control('')
    })
});
```

I'm using a [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) for `fields` because the `JSON` representation resulting from the [value](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#value) property must be an `object` and not an `array`.

How can `fields` be rendered without `*ngFor` - since `fields` is not iterable, it will not work.

---

**Detail;**

I want to render a collection of child controls belonging to an [Angular Form](https://angular.io/api/forms/Form), but *not* in a [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray).

```
// Use FromBuilder to create the form.
constructor(private readonly fb: FormBuilder) { }
```

The form must represent a structure consisting of `fields` which contain key/value pairs:

```
// Create the form with no/empty fields to start.
let form = this.fb.group({
    fields: this.fb.group({})
});
```

I don't know how many child controls will exist in `fields` - they will be added from a user action.

At this point, it's common for `fields` to be a [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray), but I must use a [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) because the representation resulting from the Form [value](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#value) must be a JSON `object` and not a JSON `array`.

At some point after the app has loaded, child controls are added to `fields` using [addControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#addControl). Control names are actually **chosen by the user**.

For simplicity I have hard-coded them here as `foo`, `bar` and `baz`:

```
const fields = form.get('fields');

const foo = new FormControl('');
fields.addControl('foo', foo);

const bar = new FormControl('');
fields.addControl('bar', bar);

...

const baz = new FormControl('');
fields.addControl('baz', baz);
```

Ideally I would used `*ngFor`, but since `controls` is not iterable, this will not work:

```
<ng-container [formGroup]="form">

  <ng-container formGroupName="fields">

       <mat-form-field *ngFor="let f of form.get('fields').controls">

         <input matInput ...>

       </mat-form-field>

  </ng-container>

</ng-container>
```

Additionally, I don't know the name of any child controls within `fields` - since as mentioned earlier, the name's of newly added controls are actually chosen by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to use `ngFor` with the keys of an object, you can simply extract those keys from the object using `Object.keys` and then loop over that array.

As it's going to be something pretty generic (you might want to reuse that), and it's going to be deal with (ideally) from the template, creating a pipe for that is a good idea:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'keys'
})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any): any[] {
    return Object.keys(value)
  }
}
```

Now you can do something like
`<div *ngFor="let a of resultForm.controls | keys">`

Another interesting part is to prevent adding a key that already exists into the form. Here's a complete example with a custom validator:

**TS:**

```
export function forbiddenFieldNameValidator(form: FormGroup): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
    const fieldToAdd: string = control.value;
    const forbidden = !!form.controls[fieldToAdd];

    return forbidden ?
      {'forbiddenFieldName': { value: control.value }} :
      null;
  };
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  resultForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});

  addFieldGroup: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    addField: ['', [Validators.required, forbiddenFieldNameValidator(this.resultForm)]]
  });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void { }

  addField(fieldName: string) {
    this.resultForm.addControl(
      fieldName,
      new FormControl('')
    );

    this.addFieldGroup.reset();
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form [formGroup]="addFieldGroup" (ngSubmit)="addField(addFieldGroup.controls['addField'].value)">
  <input type="text" formControlName="addField">

  <button type="submit" [disabled]="addFieldGroup.invalid">Add field to form</button>

  <div *ngIf="addFieldGroup.dirty && addFieldGroup.controls['addField'].errors as errors" class="error">
    <div *ngIf="errors['required']">This field is required</div>
    <div *ngIf="errors['forbiddenFieldName']">The key "{{ addFieldGroup.controls['addField'].value }}" is already into the dynamic form</div>
  </div>
</form>

Dynamic form

<form [formGroup]="resultForm">
  <div *ngFor="let controlName of resultForm.controls | keys">
    {{ controlName }} <input type="text" [formControlName]="controlName" [placeholder]="controlName">
  </div>
</form>

Form value
<pre>{{ resultForm.value | json }}</pre>
```

Here's a working stackblitz where you can try to add dynamic values into the final form and see that the input to add those values is blocked if one already exists:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w2ibtb

Side note:
For the pipe, note that we have to set it as impure because we're not directly handling the `controls` properties of the form and under the hood angular is not creating a new reference for the `controls` array every time we add a property into it. Thus, the reference passed to the pipe is the same but still, we want to update the view. That's why we have to set `pure` to false.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is make an array of Controls

```
controls:FormControl[]=[] //declare a variable
form:FormGroup //Your form

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
//When you defined the form, you create the array
this.form=this.fb.group({
    fields: this.fb.group({
      foo: this.fb.control(''),
      bar: this.fb.control(''),
      baz: this.fb.control('')
    })
    //usign map from Object.keys
    Object.keys((this.form.get('fields') as FormGroup).controls).map(control=>{
      this.controls.push((this.form.get('fields') as FormGroup).get(control) as FormControl);
    });

//Your .html is like
<div *ngFor="let control of controls">
    <input [formControl]="control">
  </div>
  {{form.value |json}}
```